# How to scrape values from a graph on a website

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape the data from three graphs:

website: https://www.worldometers.info/coronavirus/country/us/
Graph 1: Total Coronavirus Cases in the United States
Graph 2: Active Cases in the United States
Graph 3: Total Coronavirus Deaths in the United States

Till now, I have written/extracted code from stackoverflow and other locations:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import time
import json
import re

# set options to be headless, ..
from selenium import webdriver
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--headless')
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')

# open it, go to a website, and get results
driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver',options=options)
driver.get("https://www.worldometers.info/coronavirus/country/us/")

html = driver.page_source

soup = bs(html, "html.parser")

# get all scripts tags and select the one of interest
balises_script = soup.find_all("script")
target_balise = [str(el) for el in balises_script if "xAxis" in str(el)][0]

# use regex to extract dict like string 
m = re.findall(r"xAxis = (.+)\;", target_balise)[0]

# Rest of the code

# dict like string to dict
#data = json.loads(m)

# explore data to see where data of interest is
#sub_data_of_interest = data['overview']['EngagementsSimilarweb']['WeeklyTrafficNumbers']

#for items in sub_data_of_interest.items():
#    print(items)

#driver.close()
```

My question is:
what is the script tag I should target and select?
How do i extract date and corresponding numbers?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data for the graphs is in the source HTML in the `<script>` tags.

You can find those with `bs4` and extract the dates and values with some `regex` magic.

Here's how:

```py
import json
import re
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = "https://www.worldometers.info/coronavirus/country/us/"
html = requests.get(url).text

scripts = [
    script.string for script in
    BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml").find_all("script", {"type": "text/javascript"})
    if script.string is not None
]

graph_titles = [
    "Active Cases",
    "Total Coronavirus Cases",
    "Total Coronavirus Deaths",
]

output = {}

for script in scripts:
    scrip_body = script.string
    for title in graph_titles:
        if title in scrip_body:
            c = re.search(r"categories: \[(.*)\]", script.string).group(1)
            d = re.search(r"data: \[(.*)\]\s+}", script.string).group(1).split(",")
            output[title] = {
                "dates": re.findall(r"[A-Za-z]{3} \d{1,2}, \d{4}", c),
                "series": d,
            }
        else:
            continue

with open("your_graphs.json", "w") as json_file:
    json.dump(output, json_file, indent=4, sort_keys=True)
```

This should give you a `JSON` file that looks likes this:

[image]

You can then use it to plot the data (or do whatever else you want).

Comment: Thank you very much. Could you help me with putting the data in a csv file instead of json file?